# Best Practice to refer a asp.net control in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I see 4 or more ways of referring to an asp.net control in jQuery

$("input[id$='txt1']"); OR
$("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>");  OR
$("#txt1");  OR
or access using class

Can you guide which one to choose in what scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [a great discussion about this topic](http://encosia.com/2009/06/09/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/), specifically about speeding up the performance of the endsWith selector (look in the comments too for some alternate solutions as well).

Answer (score 1):

I don't like seeing inline code so I would never use $("#<%= txt1.ClientID %>");

I would probably use $("input[id$='txt1']"); since I wouldn't have duplicated names in my code and matching on the part that isn't .NET's addition will be quite reliable.

Answer (score -2):

I've been using the [endsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) selector that you have included in your question.  All other options require additional leg-work on the server-side.